# Разница между двумя условиями поиска ПОДКАТАЛОГА

Tags: c++

If(findData.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) и if(findData.attrib ==_A_SUBDIR)
Кто подскажет в чем разница.
Мой учитель сказал, что второе решение хуже первого и у второго в некоторых случаях есть проблемы. Кто-нибудь знает, что это такое? И кто знает, что может случиться, когда второе решение не сработает?

```
void listFiles(const char* dir)
{
    char dirNew[200];   //MAX_PATH_NAME (размер)
    strcpy(dirNew, dir);
    strcat(dirNew, "\\*" ); // Добавить "\\ *" после каталога для первого поиска

    badCharTable(subString, strlen(subString)); //Инициализация таблицы стоп-слов

    intptr_t hFile;
    _finddata_t findData;

    hFile = _findfirst(dirNew, &findData);
    
    if (hFile == -1) // Проверить, успешно ли это
        return;
    if (hFile == 0) //Проверка на пустую директорию 
        return;

    do
    {
        strcpy(dirNew, dir);
        strcat(dirNew, "\\");

        //Проверяем на поддиректории 
        if (findData.attrib & _A_SUBDIR)
        {
            //Игнорируем точки(спец-символы расширения)
            if (strcmp(findData.name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(findData.name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            
            //Добаляем имя директории
            strcat(dirNew, findData.name); 
            listFiles(dirNew);
        }
        else {
            //Добаляем имя файла
            strcat(dirNew, findData.name);

            // При нахождении файла открываем его и ищем подстроку
            openFile(dirNew);
            cout << "\n";
        }
    } while (_findnext(hFile, &findData) == 0);

    _findclose(hFile); // Закрыть дескриптор поиска
}
```

Comment: Это примерно как разница между "это число четное" и "это число равно 2"...

Answer (score 4):

Если у у подкаталога установлено несколько атрибутов, например `_A_SUBDIR|_A_HIDDEN`, то второй вариант не поймёт, что это каталог, и не сработает

Comment: @OlegSverkunov Ответ понятен?